# My inline-block divs are not aligned on FF and Chrome but are on Safari

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML page with two divs meant to sit next to each other.
On safari divs are perfectly aligned, but on FF and Chrome the right one is slightly lower than the left one.

Here is my CSS :

```
.desc-block-left{
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    width:35%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-left: 10%;    
    border-radius:10px;
}

.desc-block-right{
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    width:35%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-left: 5%;    
    border-radius:10px;
}
```

Comment: if you can make a jsfiddle with you html and css code then it would be helpfull to us to help you out with your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `vertical-align:top` to`..desc-block-right` and `.desc-block-left`